# MVC3 ASP.NET Objects within viewmodels?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

> Sorry, nevermind I fixed my problem. I was being stupid >< and didn't have a getter/setter in my class and got too hung up on the idea that I was doing things in the wrong way.
>
> Thanks to everyone who tried to help. :)

I'm trying to pass a view model out to my views from my controller. I have a basic ViewModel working which contains simple things like strings/ints etc but now I want to pass out an object within my view model. I've made the appropriate changes to the view model to now contain this object but I'm struggling to retrieve the data in my view.

Edit:

Sorry for not posting it all!

Here's the full thing:

```
public class StockTakeViewModel
{
    PartsViewData partsViewData = new PartsViewData();

    public StockTakeViewModel(PartsViewData PartsViewData)
    {
        partsViewData = PartsViewData;
    }
}

public class PartsViewData
{
    public string PartNum { get; set; }
    public string Issue { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string BinCode { get; set; }
    public decimal StockQty { get; set; }

    public PartsViewData()
    {
    }
}


public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        PartsViewData partsViewData = new PartsViewData();

        partsViewData.PartNum = "Part Num Test";
        partsViewData.Issue = "Issue Test";
        partsViewData.BinCode = "Bin Code Test";
        partsViewData.Location = "Location Test";
        partsViewData.StockQty = 0;

        StockTakeViewModel stockTakeViewModel = new StockTakeViewModel(partsViewData);

        return View(stockTakeViewModel);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model StockTake.Controllers.StockTakeViewModel
```

So from here I'm expecting to access parts view data with something like:

```
@Model.StockTakeViewModel.PartsViewData.PartNum
```

But StockTakeViewModel doesn't even appear.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code for the view model?

Comment: Show us code for your viewmodel

Comment: A bit more code source should be ok to figure out current situtation. Controller action and View code would be fine.

Comment: I'm a little concerned that your model is in your controllers folder but that aside, please post the code for your model.

Comment: @user1157885: Can you elaborate your problem a little further? Aren't you able to get intellisense for members other than string type OR not getting data displayed on the view? Also please make sure that those properties are having Public access.

Comment: It's in bad taste to edit out your question after you fixed your problem, this is a site about looking up answers as much as actually asking questions.

Comment: @Bindy - I agreee, so I restored the question.  user1157885 - Please leave your questions in there in the future.  Also, if you solve your problem yourself you should post your own answer and mark it as answered (though I think you need a minimum amount of reputation to do that).

Comment: To the OP: please don't destroy your question by overwriting it as you did. Just flag and we can close it off.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare `partsViewData` as a public property in your ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Model.PartsViewData.PartNum
```

The object that you pass to `View(...)` is the model, but you are calling `Model.StockTakeViewModel.PartsViewData.PartNum` (presumably making the assumption that the model is wrapped somehow based on the name of the type passed to `View(...)`).

If you added `@typeof(Model).Name` in your view, it would show `StockTakeViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your StockTakeViewModel in:

```
public class StockTakeViewModel
{
    PartsViewData partsViewData = new PartsViewData();
    public PartsViewData PartsViewData
    {
        return this.partsViewData;
    }

    public StockTakeViewModel(PartsViewData PartsViewData)
    {
        partsViewData = PartsViewData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Though i couldn't be answering your question since it was not fully explained but I would like to suggest you that, you are violating the clean seperation of concerns laid out by ASP.NET MVC template, since you kept the model inside Controllers folder/namespace. Separating/Organizing the components in correct structure even for experimentation will increase readability and understanding of the app structure.

Comment: Should have kept it deleted..